# error while booting custom minimal linux distribution: unable to mount root fs

Tags: linux, boot, grub, bootloader, linux-kernel

Recently I followed along an article describing how to build your own minimal linux distribution ([Linuxjournal article](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/diy-build-custom-minimal-linux-distribution-source))

After many tries I finally came to the point where I put my OS on a USB drive. After booting it up for the first time I was greeted by following message:

```
not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(8,0)
```

I am not sure at what point I lost the thread. How do I solve this issue?

**Filetree of OS:**
https://gist.github.com/JanikBot/25200ae9bd8e225b587daff3822ca611

**Archive of OS:**
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dous4fi4vax5wjt/horst.tar.xz?dl=0

**Grub.cfg:**

```
set default=0
set timeout=5

set root=(hd0)

menuentry "Horst" {
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.10 root=/dev/sda ro quiet
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At this point, the file tree of your root filesystem is not relevant, because the error is in fact about the kernel being *unable to access* that root filesystem in the first place.

Since you don't have an initramfs archive, then the kernel itself must be able to mount the root filesystem all on its own. Make sure the kernel was compiled with all of the options necessary to access USB storage devices, and note that they cannot be compiled as modules (because those are kept on the root filesystem).

You'll probably need these at minimum:

```
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_PCI=y
CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD=y
CONFIG_USB_STORAGE=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD=y
```

Also note that if the disk is partitioned (as most USB sticks are), then the mountable device is `/dev/sda1`, not just `/dev/sda`.

If you *did* have an initramfs (specified via 'initrd='), then its `/init` script would be responsible for finding the root device and mounting it (and modules could be used as well).

Comment: I just checked my kernel options CONFIG_USB_EHCI_PCI, CONFIG_USB_EHCI_HCD, CONFIG_USB_STORAGE and CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SD are all set to y.
Maybe the problem occures because I am unsure how to properly create an ISO image. Do you know how to properly create one?